# コミュニティの価値観や目標についてのバナーを表示させましょう！

Tags: 討議, 完了

翻訳をしてくれた[@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki)に感謝します。

---

もっと優れた回答が必要ですか？はい！さらに興味深い質問を見たいですか？もちろんです！良い質問を投稿し問題を解決する為の新たなアプローチを共有してくれる仲間を招待してみませんか？

人々を引き付ける最善の方法の一つとして、コミュニティの使命や文化、そして私達が大切にしたい価値観を共有することがあげられるのではないでしょうか。世界をより良く変えようとしている理由やスタック・オーバーフローの安全な環境が説明されています。

[コミュニティで大切にしたい価値観](/help/key-values)と[マニフェスト](/help/manifesto)についてのバナーを作成したいと思います。Stack Overflow英語版とスタック・オーバーフロー日本語版の両方に表示する予定です。

> あなたのアイデアをコミュニティと共有してください：
>
> 1. 「[マニフェスト](/help/manifesto)」と「[コミュニティで大切にしたい価値観](/help/key-values)」のページへ誘導するバナーの外観はどのようなものが良いですか？
> 2. これらのバナー作成にはどのようなスローガンや画像を使用すればよいか、何かアイデアはありますか？

これらのバナーはあなたの意見に基づいて作成され、そして沢山のプログラマーによって閲覧されるでしょう。

バナーやアイデア全体についてどうぞあなたの考えを共有してください！たくさんの意見をお待ちしております！

Comment: バナーは2種類用意されるということでしょうか？また、バナーに設定できる文字数の目安はありますか？

Comment: @cubick あなたは正しいです。 バナーには2つのタイプがあります。 制限はないと思います。 テキストが少ないほど良い=）

Answer (score 6):

ここが「ヘルプ センター > 弊社のモデル」にユーザーを誘導するバナーの大喜利会場であると想定して回答します。

日本人なら思わずクリックしたくなるバナー広告が良いと思います。

```
Geeks, be ambitious, be studious and be NICE! - SOja
```

クラーク博士の"Boys, be ambitious!"パロディです。

```
∵ リンク先 ∴ 友情 ∩ 知力 := 公利. Q.E.D.
```

リンク先を読めば『友情、努力、勝利』っぽい公式で『良識を以て知識を交わせば公共の利益となる』ことを証明できます。

```
ようこそ！我々は善き隣人を歓迎します。
```

聖書の善きサマリア人のように振る舞いましょう。

Comment: いいね！ 本当にありがとうございました！

Answer (score 3):

@payaneco さんの[ご投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3067/14055)と、何でも部屋チャットでシェアいただいた @Yuki Inoue さんの[テキスト](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54522564#54522564)を加え、以下のバナー計4つが完成しました。

素晴らしいアイデアをありがとうございました！⭐️⭐️⭐️⭐️

**「[マニフェスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto)」のページへ誘導するバナー**

[image: ようこそ！我々は善き隣人を歓迎します。]

[image: 開発者の、開発者による、開発者のための Q&A サイト]

**「[コミュニティで大切にしたい価値観](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values)」のページへ誘導するバナー**

[image: ∵ スタック・オーバーフロー ∴ 友情 ∩ 知力 := 公利. Q.E.D.]

[image: 開発者よ、大志を抱け！あと、Be Niceであってほしい。]