# 2022 モデレーター選挙 Q&A - 質問リスト

Tags: 討議, 選挙

> **この投稿の目的は、2022年度モデレーター選挙で使われるための質問をコミュニティから集めることでした。現在、質問リストは公開されており、[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election/1#questionnaire)から確認することができます。**

---

スタック・オーバーフローでは、[来週 2022-03-14](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election/1) から選挙が予定されています。これに伴い、立候補者との質疑応答を行います。コミュニティメンバーが立候補者にモデレーションについての質問をする良い機会になります。参加は完全に任意です。

詳細は以下の通りです：

- 立候補の段階まで（つまり 2022-03-15 午前 5:00 (JST)、2022-03-14 午後 1:00 (PDT)、2021-03-14 午後 8:00 (UTC)まで）質問を受け付けます。本質問リストは、サイトユーザーから潜在的な質問を集めるためのものです。候補者に回答してほしい質問をぜひこちらに投稿してください。*1つの質問を回答ごとに*投稿してください。
- 質問にリンクが含まれている場合は、完成版の質問リストをスムーズに転記できるよう`[テキスト](リンク)`の構文を使用してください。
- この機会にあなたのコミュニティが直面している課題についてどうぞお聞かせください。
- 私たちコミュニティチームは一般的な質問をする予定で、質問リストには次の2つの必須の質問が含まれます：

  - あるユーザーが、品質が高い回答を続けて投稿している一方で、コメントで多数の言い争いや通報を引き起こしている場合、どのように対処しますか？
  - クローズ/削除されるべきではないとあなたが思った質問を、別のモデレーターがクローズ/削除したという状況に、どのように対処しますか？
- コミュニティから十分な数の質問を得られなかった場合、コミュニティチームは次の3つの質問を含める予定です。

  - あなたの意見では、モデレーターとは具体的に何をするのでしょう？
  - 質問や回答、コメントなど過去に発言したものすべての横にダイヤモンドマークが加えられ、これから発言することに対してもフィルターがかかります。そのような状況についてどう思いますか？
  - 単に [モデレーターツールへのアクセス (2,000)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) 或いは [信頼できるユーザー (4,000)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) の信用度に達するというのではなく、あなたはモデレーターになることによってさらにどのように効果的になると思いますか？
- 立候補の段階が始まる時、コミュニティチームは前述の2つの必須の質問に加えて、本投稿で**コミュニティによってプラス票が多く集められた上位8つの質問**を選択します。質問の選択には編集上の管理を留保し、内容が脱線したもの、モデレーションや選挙に関係のない質問を選択しない場合もあります。合計スコアがマイナスになっている質問は除外されます。

  - 最終的な質問リストは [選挙ページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election/1) に掲載されます。候補者は質問リストに記載するオプションがあり、回答は紹介文の下に表示されます。
  - これはユーザーが候補者に関する情報を収集するための唯一の選択肢というわけではありません。コミュニティとして、例えば、候補者とのライブチャットセッションでさらに質問し、Q&A の内容についての説明を得ることもできるでしょう。

このプロセスについて質問やフィードバックがある場合は、どうぞお気軽にコメントとして投稿してください。

**参考:**

英語版における 2021 年モデレーター選挙の質問リスト (候補)
[2021 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411988)
実際に確定した質問は [こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13#questionnaire)

Comment: @aki 原文の "10k or 20k rep" はそれぞれ「モデレーションツールへのアクセス」「信頼できるユーザー」を指していますが、日本語版において現時点では 2,000 と 4,000 に緩和されたままの状態なはずです。また、ここを漢数字に翻訳してしまうのは分かりづらいと思います。

Comment: @cubick 本当ですね、昨夜は原文を急いで直訳したのですが、今朝確認しましたら仰る通り日本語版では2,000と4,000を指していますね。日本語版ヘルプページのリンクを加えられた点も親切なアクションだと思います。どうもありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

せっかくの機会なので、スタッフが質問しにくいであろう質問を出してみます。

- もしも類似のIT系QAサイトが存在するとします。そのサイトはスタック・オーバーフローよりも会員数が多く質問と回答が活発であり、モデレーターがいない代わりにコメントが自由であると**仮定**した時、あなたはスタック・オーバーフローをそのサイト(仮)と差別化または模倣したいですか？モデレーターとしてSOjaをどのようなコミュニティに導きたいのかをお聞かせください。

Answer (score 2):

この質問は純粋な興味からの質問です。

- スタック・オーバーフローでは交流会やもくもく会、バナー募集など様々な企画が催されてきました。モデレーター就任後はこのような企画に参加または運営したいでしょうか。企画を今まで以上に盛り上げたり参加者を増やす方策はありますか？企画に対する姿勢や考えをご教示ください。また、新たな企画を開きたいなどの案や展望があればお聞かせください。

下記は企画の参考リンクです。(質問に含む必要はありません)

[スタック・オーバーフローの交流会](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2511/9820)
[東京・渋谷MeetUp](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2982/9820)
[第1回もくもく会](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3235/9820)
[第2回もくもく会](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3355/9820)
[第3回もくもく会](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3497/9820)
[オリジナルバナー作成について](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2915/9820)
[コミュニティの価値観や目標についてのバナーを表示させましょう！](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3060/9820)
[コミュニティ広告の案を募集しています (2020年)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3333/9820)
[ベータ卒業記念イベントを企画しよう](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3683/9820)

Answer (score 2):

モデレーターは、クローズ投票や再オープン投票をすると[一発でクローズや再オープンされます](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2517)。またこれを回避して通常の投票を行う方法は[ありません](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41062)。さて、では、普通のユーザーのクローズ票が集まってクローズされたものの、あなたが考えるにそのクローズは適切でなく、再オープンすべきだと信じる質問があったとします。あなたならこのような状況でどうなさいますか？